# Meteor 1.7 bundler is broken

Tags: meteor, npm-install

I am trying to deploy an app that has been upgraded to meteor 1.7 using the setup for passenger outlined at [puhsionpasserger.com](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/ownserver/nginx/oss/xenial/deploy_app.html), however when I try and access the app I get an error in the console of

```
Error: The core-js npm package could not be found in your node_modules directory. Please run the following command to install it: meteor npm install --save core-js
```

Being shown on the web page (although the favercon is correct so its trying).

The app runs fine locally (as in on the dev machine).

Give its deployed, meteor doesn't exist on the machine.

I tried npm install --save core.js and it reported one package installed, but still no joy on the app front.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any thoughts?

Edit:
I just tried building the app without the --server-only flag with no change. Deployed the app the way I do with the v1.3 instances of the app and no change.

One thing that I did get when running npm intall  from the /programs/server directory was

Binary is fine; exiting
npm WARN lifecycle meteor-dev-bundle@~install: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) meteor-dev-bundle@ node npm-rebuild.js /opt/bundle/programs/server
added 131 packages in 13.857s

I'm not sure if the warning means anything in particular.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling meteor?

Comment: Does it run, when deploying manually / running without passenger using `cd bundle && node main.js` ?

Comment: When run manually, I get the same behavior. No errors on the console, but the same message displayed in the web console.

Comment: I've done some more looking at this and can see the core-js directory under /var/www/appname/bundle/programs/server. This is really strange.

Comment: Usually this means that you didn't `meteor npm install --save core-js`, and you need to do that, and build again - have you tried that?

Comment: Mikkel, that solved the issue, also running npm install on the remote server as a normal user, not root.